# Keyboard is hid when alertview show up on iOS 8.3

Tags: keyboard, uialertview, ios8.3

The keyboard is hid when UIAlertView show on iOS 8.3 ,and it will show after the alertView dismiss.

So there is a problem: 
**A** view -> **B** view(has UITextField) -> keyboard(**custom**) show -> alertView show(keyboard hide) -> user clicke -> **B** view dismiss -> **A** view & keyboard show(this keyboard belongs to **B** view, and it crash when I click).

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Issue is iOS8. You need to hide keyboard by adding some logic like [self.view endEditing = YES];

Comment: thanks, it is a good solution~

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions.

Like Gajendra said : hide keyboard by adding some logic like [self.view endEditing = YES];

We can also use this delegate method to handle alertview click

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex